# zsh history is too short

Tags: zsh, history

When I run `history` in Bash, I get a load of results (1000+). However, when I run `history` the zsh shell I only get 15 results. This makes grepping history in zsh mostly useless. 
My `.zshrc` file contains the following lines:

```
HISTFILE=~/.zhistory
HISTSIZE=SAVEHIST=10000
setopt sharehistory
setopt extendedhistory
```

How can I fix zsh to make my shell history more useful?

---

UPDATE

If in zsh I call `history 1` I get all of my history, just as I do in Bash with `history`. I could alias the command to get the same result, but I wonder why does `history` behave differently in zsh and in Bash.

Comment: As an alternative to grepping through history, I can strongly recommend fzf (https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) - it allows fuzzy search in your shell history on ctrl+r.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

NVaughan (the OP) has already stated the answer in an update to the question: **`history` behaves differently in `bash` than it does in `zsh`**:

In short:

- **zsh**:

  - `history` lists only the **15 most recent** history entries
  - `history 1` lists **all** - see below.
- **bash**:

  - `history` lists **all** history entries.

Sadly, passing a **numerical operand** to `history` behaves differently, too:

- **zsh**:

  - `history <n>` shows all entries ***starting with* `<n>`** - therefore, `history 1` shows *all* entries.
  - (`history -<n>` - note the `-` - shows the **`<n>` *most recent*** entries, so the default behavior is effectively `history -15`)
- **bash**:

  - `history <n>` shows the **`<n>` *most recent*** entries.
  - (bash's `history` doesn't support listing *from* an entry number; you can use `fc -l <n>`, but a *specific entry `<n>` must exist*, otherwise the command fails - see below.)

---

Optional background info:

- In zsh, `history` is effectively (not actually) an alias for `fc -l`: see `man zshbuiltins`

  - For the many history-related features, see `man zshall`
- In bash, `history` is its own command whose syntax differs from `fc -l`

  - See: `man bash`
- Both bash and zsh support `fc -l <fromNum> [<toNum>]` to list a given *range* of history entries:

  - bash: specific entry `<fromNum>` must exist.
  - zsh: command succeeds as long as least 1 entry falls in the (explicit or implied) range.
  - Thus, `fc -l 1` works in zsh to return all history entries, whereas in bash it generally won't, given that entry #1 typically no longer exists (but, as stated, you can use `history` without arguments to list all entries in bash).

Comment: Is there a way to change the default number of lines of output in zsh's `history`? (other than the obvious `alias history="fc -l $NUMBER`)

Comment: **Oh my zsh** sets a shell alias `history=omz_history` which lists all the history. https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/53863e7b3ff0c2e2816e90dab3d870adebdf49c7/lib/history.zsh

Answer (score 25):

```
#set history size
export HISTSIZE=10000
#save history after logout
export SAVEHIST=10000
#history file
export HISTFILE=~/.zhistory
#append into history file
setopt INC_APPEND_HISTORY
#save only one command if 2 common are same and consistent
setopt HIST_IGNORE_DUPS
#add timestamp for each entry
setopt EXTENDED_HISTORY
```

this is my setting, and it work

Comment: +1 for _useful settings_, but it doesn't answer the question (`history` (without arguments) in `zsh` only shows the 15 most recent entries, so the problem was a _display_ problem).

Comment: FYI: bck-i-search (reverse history search in zsh) will search the entire history (>history 1)

Comment: how did you get the timestamp after setopt EXTENDED_HISTORY ?

Comment: on mac you would still need to alias history to history 1

Answer (score 13):

Perhaps late however coming across this post and trying to apply it, and failed .... so in practical terms, put this in `.zshrc` :

```
alias history='history 1'
```

and you'll see anything until the `HIST_SIZE` runs out. To find a command I use (after the `.zshrc` change)

```
history | grep "my_grep_string"
```

Comment: It is always a bit precarious to change the meaning of a command... it might be better to define `alias hist='history 1'` so the meaning of the original `history` isn't affected (in case there are scripts etc that use it). In general I like the idea of using an alias to make life easier.

Comment: yes this is required on mac, at least for me

Comment: Ctrl + R instead of history|grep ?