# How to undo a sed cli .zsh

Tags: sed, terminal, command-line-interface, zsh, undo

I am on ***Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS***

As I use very often **"clear"** in my zsh terminal, I wanted to delete it from my `.zshrc_history` file.
I found this command line : `sed -i '/string/d' .bash_history`  here [ZSH / BASH : Delete specific lines from history](https://superuser.com/questions/1316668/zsh-bash-delete-specific-lines-from-history).

I know there is no up vote for it, but I did it with my own configuration : 
**`sed -i '/clear/d' .zsh_history`** (**clear** as the word I wanted to **delete**)

---

But now when I type **history** in my zsh shell, I have only a few lines shown. I think the lines before hitting the first **clear** and not all my history.

As I write in the zsh, it now keeps only theses few lines and not incrementing the lines (so the first history line is hidden to show the new one and I always have only 16 lines in my history).

When I open my .zshrc_history file, I have all my history shown as this :

`1 : 1543529720:0;sudo apt-get install zsh-syntax-highlighting
  ... etc.
1556 : 1549402753:0;ls
1557 : 1549403085:0;code .zsh_history
1558 : 1549403818:0;source .zshrc
1559 : 1549405008:0;npm -v`

---

**Is there a way to undo this command and have all my history back shown in my shell ?**
Thanks for your help.

*If you speaks french it is even better for my understanding*

> UPDATE

Hi @jhnc that's right my .zshrc_history has everything from line 1.
I already backup this .zshrc_history file, thanks to mention it.
So I did 
`echo $HISTSIZE $SAVEHIST $HISTFILE` and here is the result :
`50000 10000 /home/echayotte/.zsh_history`

I started with bash before using zsh this is why I put them both :

- in .zshrc_history
  Line 1 shows :
  `: 1543529608:0;sudo apt-get install powerline fonts-powerline`
- in .bash_history
  Line 1 shows :
  `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer`

In my folder I have this icons and before that they were the same as the bash history
[icons of .zsh/bash_history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYzJc.png)

> UPDATE

So I create a new .zsh_history file but the problem is unsolved.
I don't know what to do ...
**Do I need to reinstall zsh; This will fix my problem ?**

Comment: Just restore your .zsh_history from the backup file you made of it before executing that un-recommended, unproven sed command google found for you on some web site.

Comment: Oups I didn't made a backup file... So nothing to do for me.
Is it possible to create a new .zsh_history file ? Starting from 0 and I keep in other file the old history ?

Comment: your question says you ran a sed command on .zshrc_history and now it still contains your history when you look inside, is that right?

Comment: What does `echo $HISTSIZE $SAVEHIST $HISTFILE` show you?

Comment: before you do anything else, I'd copy that history file somewhere else as a backup. sounds like it still contains content but that zsh isn't showing it all for some reason

Comment: that's good. what does `history 1` show?

Comment: I put the answer in my first message at the bottom

Comment: Maybe is to convert this .zshrc_history binary file into text file ? Is there a good way to do this ?

Comment: If `history 1` shows your commands, then there is nothing to restore. `history` by itself only displays 15 lines: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26846738/zsh-history-is-too-short

Comment: Well I disagree because before writing this line, when I typed "history", I had plenty of lines, not just 15.

Comment: Well I don't completely disagree, but before doing this sed line, I haven't touch my .zshrc file and all my history was here everytime. So don't know why I always had all my history before ;-)